# how to use sed to print line #6 from a file, but only if any other line in the file matches a pattern

Tags: sed

and, in a more generic way, is it possible to use program sed to print any line matching PATTERN 1, but only if any other line in the file matches PATTERN 2? It can be done with a combination of grep commands, but I am trying to get it done with a single sed command.

Comment: `awk` would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand the need to use `sed` for this, whereas `awk` is the master for such things.

Comment: post sample input and expected output. And don't start your question on the subject line and continue it in the description as it just makes it hard to read and irritating. Post a complete brief subject and a complete but more detailed description. sed is just for performing simple substitutions on individual lines while awk is a general purpose text manipulation tool so this is clearly a job for awk, not for sed.

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT a job for sed:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/PATTERN2/) f=1; next} f && (FNR==6)' file file

awk 'NR==FNR{if (/PATTERN2/) f=1; next} f && /PATTERN1/' file file
```

or if you don't want to specify the file name twice:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC]=ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++} NR==FNR{if (/PATTERN2/) f=1; next} f && /PATTERN1/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's possible:

```
:l1 {
    /foo/ { H }
    /bar/ { x ; s/^\n//; p ; s/.*//; h ; b l2}
    n
    b l1
}

:l2 {
    /foo/ { p }
    n
    b l2
}
```

Quick overview:

l1 is our initial loop. It will check for `/foo/` (being pattern 1). If it's found on a line, that line will be APPENDED to the holding space.
The next line will check for `/bar/`, when found, it will exchange the holding space and pattern space (`x`), remove an initial newline from the data (this is because we use `H` in our first line, we `p`rint the data, we empty this data and store it back in the holding pattern (so it will be empty). Then, we `b`ranch to `l2`, in effect, leaving the loop `l2`.

If the line does not match pattern 1 `foo` or pattern 2 `bar`, it will go to the next line, and jump back to the start `l1` again.

Once we are in `l2`, we check for pattern 1 `/foo/`. Since we KNOW that we have found pattern 2 earlier (otherwise we wouldn't be here), we can safely print this data. If not foo, we just skip that line, and loop back to the start of `l2`.

Pretty much tested this with the following data:

```
a
b
c foo
d
e foo
f bar
g foo
h
i foo
j
k
```

Depending on "bar" being there, it will either print all lines with `foo`, or nothing at all.

Granted, it will not win any beauty contests, but it's written in sed only.

Comment: Won't work if the patterns occur in the opposite order.

Comment: True.. But maybe, you could branch to a loop when pattern 2 is found, which dumps the pattern (or hold) space, and directly prints any additional matches on pattern 1?

Comment: `sed` does loops? I'd be more than intrigued to see a `sed` script that do loops using the rudimentary labels and branches that its language provides. I'm not saying it can't be done (in fact, I'm sure it's possible), I've just never seen `sed` script that sophisticated...  :-)

Comment: Yes, sed knows about unconditional and even conditional branching. It's not really sophisticated per se, but in most cases, pointless, as other tools would probably be more suited for the job (as already pointed out by others). But still, they can be used for really cool and complex things.

Comment: @JayTaph My answer works with the patterns in any order.

Comment: Looks nice, but I get `sed: 2: script.sed: extra characters at the end of H command`. If I correct it, I get `sed: 12: script.sed: unexpected }`. I'm using the sed that ships with Mac OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: Try this `sed -n ':loop {/foo/H;/bar/{g;s/\n//;/foo/p;:loop2 {n;/foo/p;b loop2;};};n;b loop;}' file`

Comment: I think there were unnecessary braces causing the problem. I have edited it and heres the new script in a one liner:
`sed -n ':loop; /foo/H;/bar/{g;s/\n//;/foo/p;:loop2; n;/foo/p;b loop2;};n;b loop' file`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed script that prints lines matching pattern1, if there exists a line matching pattern2, regardless of the order of pattern1, pattern2:

```
#n
:loop 
    /foo/H
    /bar/{      
        g
        s/\n//
        /foo/p          
        :loop2 
            n
            /foo/p              
            b loop2         
    }
    n
    b loop
```

If you save this into a file like s.sed, you can do

```
sed -f s.sed file
```

The `#n` works the same way as -n, meaning suppress standard output. The `loop` appends any lines matching foo (pattern1) to the hold space. When it encounters bar (pattern2), it gets the contents of the hold space (wiping out the current pattern space) with the `g` command. It removes the first new line (as the `H` command adds a new line even when the hold space is empty). It prints out the pattern space if it contains foo (meaning its not empty). Then the `n` goes to the next line. Now that we have matched pattern2, we can safely print all matches of foo by starting `loop2`

Comment: I deleted my answer since it would require to parse the hold space again after processing the whole file. Especially if there are a lot of lines containing bar this is unnecessary overhead. That's worth a plus one. Your solution looked a bit complicated in the first place, but it isn't. Btw, you should try to address your concerns in a more kindly way, the feedback would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;6H;/pattern/{z;H};n;$!ba;x;s/\n//;s///p' file
```

Turn off automatic printing of the pattern space by using option `-n`. Set up a loop that reads every line of the file and appends a single line (for line 6) and/or(not) an empty line (denoting a match on `pattern` has occurred) in the hold space. At the end of the file swap to the hold space, remove the ever present first newline (if a line or an empty line has been appended) and removes a second newline and prints the result if successful.

N.B. If `pattern` exists in the file the hold space will contain two newlines either the first two characters or the first and the last characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this in the general case without parsing the file twice. This means invoking `sed` twice.

If the line(s) matching the "trigger pattern" always occur after all occurrences of the line(s) matching the "match pattern", then this might do it for you:

```
$ cat testdata
1 aaa
2 match
3 match
4 ddd
5 trigger (only print line 2 and 3 if this line is present)

$ sed -n -e '/match/H' -e '/trigger/{x;^Mp;^M;q^M}' testdata

2 match
3 match
```

(the `^M` in there are verbatim newlines)

I'm not sure how to delete the initial empty line in the output. Pointers about this are welcomed.

UPDATE: I put a final `q` (quit) at the end of the command sequence for the "trigger pattern" just to make sure that further trigger patterns later in the file wouldn't screw up the output.

Comment: Yes you can do it without parsing twice. I've added a solution for this in my answer.